# Perfect participle

Tags: expressions

The first pair of these sentences with perfect participles, shows a reason while the second shows a time, and this is how the teacher taught me their meaning, so I want to know why one is reason and the other is time. How can I know that one describes reason and the other time? Please convince me.

> He has failed four times already, he doesn't want to appear in the examination again. (Reason)
>
> Having failed four times, he doesn't want to appear in the examination again. (Reason)

> He has a lot of money in business, he doesn't want to risk his money any more. (Time)
>
> Having lost a lot of money in business, he doesn't want to risk his money any more. (Time)

Comment: Where are these examples from? (1) and (3) aren't even grammatically correct; they're comma splices.

Comment: Mega english book of modern English grammar

Comment: I can't see much point in this time/reason analysis. Where is it supposed to lead the learner? I suspect it is unnecessary low-level grammatical formalism that has little application to understanding or sentence construction.

Comment: @Shine You need to provide the full source/context, because these examples don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why one is reason and the other is time.

I have no idea where that idea came from. They are both clauses of reason.

> He has failed four times already, [**and therefore**] he doesn't want to appear in the examination again. (Reason)

> Having failed four times, he **[, therefore,]** doesn't want to appear in the examination again. (Reason)

> He has lost a lot of money in business, [**and therefore**] he doesn't want to risk his money any more. (Reason)

> Having lost a lot of money in business, [**he therefore**] he doesn't want to risk his money any more. (Reason)

Comment: He found no one in the house, he came back. Finding no one in the house , he came back ( reason or time)

Comment: @Shine Can you explain why that would have anything to do with time?